# Fitting irregular shape into circle

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, geometry

I have a bitmap with an alpha channel, showing an irregular shape. I try to scale and shift the shape to fit into a circle of given radius. Any ideas how to do this in an efficient way? This will have to be calculated at runtime.

Precision can be 1..2 pixels, it is more important not to cut away from the shape. I suppose it can be done by stepping through offset and scale values, drawing and checking for collisions, but this sounds kind of expensive.

[image: schematic view]

Solutions involving Swift/iOS greatly appreciated…

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, scan the image to find all foreground pixels, and compute their convex hull (use the [monotone chain](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) approach, taking linear time O(N) as you can detect the points in sorted order). This will strongly reduce the number of points to consider.

Then you can find the [smallest enclosing circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem), which can be constructed in linear time O(H).

[image]

Lookup [Nayuki's Smallest Enclosing Circle](https://www.nayuki.io/page/smallest-enclosing-circle) for what seems to be a clean implementation of the randomized algorithm.

Comment: I am afraid that you will find few algorithmic resources in Swift, due to the youthfulness of the language.

Comment: You can skip the convex hull step, and just feed all the foreground pixel coordinates into the smallest enclosing circle algorithm. It runs in expected linear time, after all.

Comment: The convex hull can be computed very efficiently, you can consider the horizontal runs of black pixels and keep only the endpoints. This will bring you much closer to H points; this is quite beneficial for the smallest enclosing construction, which has a less favorable asymptotic constant.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to fit the surrounding rectangle of the image (i suppose the image size is cut to just enclose the image without any white borders) into the circle. As you know the radius of the circle (i hope), the scale factor for the image should be

```
scaleFactor = (circle diameter) / (longest diagonal of image)
```

Then center the scaled image on the circle and done.

Comment: Yes, that's a possible solution, but it might give away several pixels. In the example I depicted, look at the top right corner. The bounding box of the flag would go clearly into the grey area, so the scaling of your proposal would be smaller than necessary. An even more extreme example would be an equilateral triangle or a circle.

Comment: Of course you get the additional problem of images that don't scale right to fit in the circle, in those cases you also have to define which dimension of the image to fit.